# Combobox SelectedValue not being set in binding XAML but works in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I have a model in WPF which i am binding to a window.

```
pageData
```

holds all my data and includes one field:

```
pageData.orders.PrefContact
```

On tests on the page, this is being populated by the model (integer 1->4)

I ahve this XAML:

```
    <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtLastName" Text="{Binding Path = order.LastName}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 TabIndex="1" LostFocus="txtLastName_LostFocus" />

<Label Content="Contact Method" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPrefContact" SelectedValue="{Binding Path = order.PrefContact}" SelectionChanged="cmbPrefContact_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="3"   
                          Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     TabIndex="3"  Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

In this case the textbox txtLastName is populated correctly, hopefully showing that the model is attached correctly to the XAML.

Within my C# I have a section to create the combobox:

```
private void bindCmbPref(int cmbpref)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/comboData/contactPrefData");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

            var JsonString = response.Content;
            var contactPrefData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<contactPrefData>(JsonString);

            foreach (var contactPrefs in contactPrefData.ContactPrefs)
            {
                
                cmbPrefContact.Items.Add(contactPrefs);
                cmbPrefContact.SelectedValuePath = "contactPrefID";
                cmbPrefContact.DisplayMemberPath = "ContactType";
            }
           
            //cmbPrefContact.SelectedValue = cmbpref;
            
        }
```

I have created it this way as to be honest...I don't understand the whole model/MVVM thing yet and after hours have given up on it. (for the moment).
I was hoping to create the combo this way but then set the combo using the binding like my text boxes however it is not working.

If I allow the end code to work above in the c# code I can set the SelectedValue using the variable which is taken from pageData.orders.PrefContact.

What am I doing wrong here that the binding isnt working for the combobox?

EDIT:
My model is below for the contactPrefs, which is a result JSON from the API I have made.

```
public partial class contactPrefData
    {
        public bool Result { get; set; }
        public List<contactPrefs> ContactPrefs { get; set; }

        public partial class contactPrefs
        {
            public int contactPrefID { get; set; }
            public string ContactType { get; set; }            
        }


    }
```

My pageData comes from this model:

```
public partial class OrderResponse
    {
        public bool Result { get; set; }
        public Order order { get; set; }

        public partial class Order
        {
            public long OrderId { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Phone { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public int PrefContact { get; set; }
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
            public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }
            public string Plu { get; set; }
            public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
        }
}
```

C# where the order model is set to the page dataContext:

```
pageData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderResponse>(JsonString);

            DataContext = pageData;
```

If order.PrefContact = 1:
[image]
[image]

HOWEVR if I change in DB and order.PrefContact = 2:
[image]
[image]

**CURRENT WORKING SITUATION:**
C#:

```
cmbPrefContact.ItemsSource = contactPrefData.ContactPrefs;
cmbPrefContact.SelectedValuePath = "contactPrefID";
cmbPrefContact.DisplayMemberPath = "ContactType";
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbPrefContact" 
                      
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path = order.PrefContact}"
                      SelectedValuePath ="contactPrefID"  
                      DisplayMemberPath  ="contactType"
                      SelectionChanged="cmbPrefContact_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="3"   
                      Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 TabIndex="3"  Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

So now I guess I'm not sure why I need to designate display member and value paths in the C# AND the XAML... but if i take one of them away on either side it stops working!

This is my contact prefs data being loaded into the combobox:

```
{
    "Result": true,
    "contactPrefs": [
        {
            "contactPrefID": 1,
            "ContactType": "SMS"
        },
        {
            "contactPrefID": 2,
            "ContactType": "Phone Call"
        },
        {
            "contactPrefID": 3,
            "ContactType": "Email"
        },
        {
            "contactPrefID": 4,
            "ContactType": "None"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Database infoo showing teh id for prefContact]

Final working code, worked out by mm8:
XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbPrefContact" 
                      
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path = order.PrefContact}"
                      SelectedValuePath ="contactPrefID"  
                      DisplayMemberPath  ="ContactType"
                      SelectionChanged="cmbPrefContact_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="3"   
                      Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 TabIndex="3"  Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

C#:

```
var JsonString = response.Content;
            var contactPrefData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<contactPrefData>(JsonString);
                       
            cmbPrefContact.ItemsSource = contactPrefData.ContactPrefs;
```

Comment: Bind the `SelectedValue` property assuming that `order.PrefContact` is an `int`: `SelectedValue="{Binding Path = order.PrefContact}"`. Could you post an example of where and how the `LastName` and `PrefContact` properties are defined.

Comment: And of course set `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` in XAML.

Comment: Also, instead of looping over `contactPrefData.ContactPrefs` and set items one by one, just set `cmbPrefContact.ItemsSource = contactPrefData.ContactPrefs;`

Comment: bugger, i did have selected VALUE not item, I was just trying ITEM before I posted on here as value wasnt working either.

Comment: @Clemens I have changed them as suggested, thanks, but the SelectedValue="{Binding Path = order.PrefContact}" didn't work, I actually tried that before and have changed it back now

Comment: @mm8 I have updated question with more code including that info. I have tried your suggestion but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the `SelectedValue` property to the `int` source property:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbPrefContact" SelectedValue="{Binding order.PrefContact}" ... />
```

`SelectedItem` is supposed to be bound to a `contactPrefs` property.

You should also replace the `foreach` loop by setting the `ItemsSource`:

```
cmbPrefContact.ItemsSource = contactPrefData.ContactPrefs;
```

...and the `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` in XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbPrefContact" ... SelectedValuePath = "contactPrefID" DisplayMemberPath = "ContactType" />
```

Comment: bugger, i did have selected VALUE not item, I was just trying ITEM before I posted on here as value wasnt working either.

Comment: What is `order`?

Comment: I just added the code for the order section. order is a .. sub list inside my json! Sorry I dont know the terminology.  Bottom of my question is that section

Comment: What's the value of `order.PrefContact`? Is that value present in the `ComboBox`?

Comment: order.PrefContact = 1

If i do Console.writeline(pageData.order.PrefContact) I get 1

ok WEIRDLY 1 works and displays the first combobox item, 
but if i change database to 2,3 or 4, none of them work. Ill add image

Comment: Are there any items with contactPrefID = 2,3 or 4 in the `ComboBox` then?

Comment: Added update and a solution.. but Im not sure this is "correct" in terms of how this should be done.

Comment: @GlennAngel: You didn't answer my last question.

Comment: sorry, yes there  are, Ive added pics, the data is 1,2,3,4 as ID

Comment: @GlennAngel: I doubt there is a `contactPrefID` matching the current `order.PrefContact` when there is no item selected.

Comment: I have added more pics at bottom to show the raw data that is being extracted.  Thanks for your time so far.
As you can see also at bottom of qu i have added a working code, but I'm confused as I didn't think it would be correct to state paths twice.

Comment: sorry, it wasnt relevant as it was just catching the current selected value and changing visibility of another textbox. (if (curPref == 3)
            {
                lblEmail.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                txtEmail.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                txtEmail.Focus();
            }

Comment: Ok so I have this working now:
- set itemsource in C#
--IN XAML
- set selectedValue ="{Binding Path = order.PrefContact}"
- SelectedValuePath ="contactPrefID"
- DisplayMemberPath  ="contactType"

Comment: I found the errror with the Xaml.  the ID was correct but the member path had a ContactType string but I had typed contactType (lower c).  I knew these were case sensitive so I ahve no idea how I did that

As per previous message I now have the working answer and will post as answer, thanks all to you :)

Comment: I have added this though, SelectedValue="{Binding Path = order.PrefContact}"
I have used Path, where in your answer it doesnt have path.
Is it possible to add itemssource into my xaml so it is all bound that way insdead of doing that part in c#?

Comment: You can omit `Path = `. You could bind the `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable<contactPrefs>` property.